# Android dynamic features on Expo modules

Tags: android, react-native, expo, dynamic-feature-module, expo-module

I have a project that needs to integrate an external library that requires a minSdkVersion of 30+. The problem is that I don't want to make my whole app min sdk version 30+ since I have maybe 15% of my users that are 29-. So I'm trying to use Android dynamic features that supposedly helps you deliver optional modules to you users. The end goal being :

Users with API level 30+ => External library installed
Users with API level 29- => External library not installed but can still use the rest of the app

I can't find any information or example of people integrating it with a modern expo modules. I've tried many things for weeks now but can't make it work. Is there anyone with good android and expo modules knowledge that could help me ?

I tried creating a dynamic feature module in Android studio after having prebuild my expo app but the dependency from the dynamic feature module to the app modules makes the app crash at launch because is loops on some SoLoader stuff.

Thank you !